# How to pivot few columns of a table and get the results in desired format.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, pivot-table

How to pivot the below table to achieve the desired result.The txtItem Values are not fixed,there can be n number of txtItem Values..

```
txtItem  Rate  Revenue  Cost

   A      1200    45      30

   B      1300    55      40

   C      1400    60      30

   D      2100    55      35
```

Result Expected :

```
  ColumnName      A       B      C      D

  Rate          1200    1300   1400   2100

  Revenue        45      55     60     55

  Cost           30      40     30     35
```

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: Does the `txtItem` values range from A to D? or you may have more? And what is the query you came up with?

Comment: The txtItem values are not fixed..it may increase also

Answer (score 1):

This is the `unvpivot` & `pivot`, so you can do :

```
select colname, 
       max(case when txtItem = 'A' then val end) as A,
       max(case when txtItem = 'B' then val end) as B,
       max(case when txtItem = 'C' then val end) as C,
       max(case when txtItem = 'D' then val end) as D
from table t cross apply
     ( values (1, Rate, 'Rate'), (2, Revenue, 'Revenue'), (3, Cost, 'Cost') 
     ) tt(seq, val, colname)
group by seq, colname
order by seq;
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to transpose this table, perform an unpivot and then the pivot response

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#TEMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
GO

CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    txtItem nvarchar(1),
    Rate int,
    Revenue int,
    Cost int
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
    ('A', 1200, 45, 30),
    ('B', 1300, 55, 40),
    ('C', 1400, 60, 30),
    ('D', 2100, 55, 35)



SELECT [ColumnName], [A],[B],[C],[D]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #TEMP
    UNPIVOT
    (VALUE FOR ColumnName IN ([Rate],[Revenue],[Cost])
    ) UPV
) TAB
PIVOT
(
    SUM(VALUE)
    FOR txtItem IN ([A],[B],[C],[D])
) PIV
```

Answer (score 0):

using unpivot and pivot

```
select name, [A], [B], [C],[D]
from
(
  select txtItem, name, value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value for name in (Rate, Revenue, cost)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for txtItem in ([A], [B], [C],[D])
) piv

name    A      B      C     D
cost    30    40      30    35
Rate    1200  1300    1400  2100
Revenue 45    55      60    55
```

[Demo in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92a31393fa9053a80439d71b4af7a856)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your txtItems are fix, you can UNPIVOT your `BelowTable` and then PIVOT the result:

```
SELECT ColumnName, A, B, C, D
FROM BelowTable
UNPIVOT (Amount FOR ColumnName IN (Rate, Revenue, Cost)) upvt
PIVOT (SUM(Amount) FOR txtItem IN (A, B, C, D)) pvt;
```